# Tabs with fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-tabs

I have 2 tabs and 2 fragments.I did all for this guide

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

but now I see tabs but dont see my fragments.What is the problem?
ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Direct tab1 = new Direct();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                AdventuresFragment tab2 = new AdventuresFragment();
                return tab2;


            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Activity with using this adapter:

```
public class TabsActivity extends Activity {

    Fragment directFragmentTab = new Direct();
    Fragment adventuresFragmentTab = new AdventuresFragment();
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        }

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                () {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity you are using the PagerAdapter class while your fragment handling class is named ViewPagerAdapter. You want to use the ViewPagerAdapter class instead.